# Flask MVC - duvidas

Tags: python, mvc, flask

Eu com duvidas em fazer que a minha aplicação torne o mais organizada possível,  estou tendo dificuldades em implementar o MVC ...  [image: <code>inserir a descrição da imagem aqui</code>]

Esse é o arquivo que inicia a aplicação

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__,template_folder='template' )

app.run(debug=True)
```

Esse é o aquivo das Views

```
from flask import render_template, redirect, request

from App import app

from settings import REPOSITORY_NAME, REPOSITORY_SETTINGS


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template(
        'template.html')
```

Só que eu não consigo fazer que o templete seja renderizado pelo render_template
da um erro 404.
O que eu posso estar fazendo de errado?

---

consegui fazer dessa forma funcionar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o runservice.py ficou dessa forma

```
from project import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Dento da pasta Controllers temos o **init**.py e views.py

**init**.py

```
 import os, glob
    __all__ = [os.path.basename(f)[:-3]
    for f in glob.glob(os.path.dirname(__file__)+'/*.py')]
```

Views.py

```
from project import app
from flask import render_template, request
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired


class CreateForm(FlaskForm):
    texto = StringField('name', validators=[DataRequired])

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('printer/index.html')
```

na Raiz da pasta projetct temos o **init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask('project')
app.debug = True


from project.controllers import *
```

PS: não sei se é a melhor forma de trabalhar, mas consegui o resultado esperado! 
Caso alguém tenha uma melhor solução gostaria de saber!

Answer (score 1):

Você definiu uma template folder com o nome de `template` aqui: `template_folder='template'`

Porém pela imagem é possível verificar que a pasta que você criou chama-se `templates` no plural!

Então talvez seja o caso de somente acertar isso, renomeando a pasta ou alterando o código.

Comment: ainda continua dando 404

Comment: Consegui fazer de outra forma, mas tive que mudar a estrutura do "PROJETO", vou colocar logo a baixo

Answer (score 1):

Veja como o `ocomunitário` foi feito.

https://github.com/DwarfTeam/ocomunitario

eu tento segui as boas práticas sempre.

Entenda uma coisa, esse é seu código:

`app = Flask(__name__,template_folder='template' )`

Você pede para o flask enxergar para uma pasta chamada template, porém a sua pasta mostrada na imagem tem o nome de : `templates` com o s no final, por isso ele não consegue encontrar o arquivo e da erro 404.

Comment: eu mudei para templetes e mesmo assim dava 404

Comment: tire o `template_folder='template'` e me diga o que retorna quando você tenta acessar. Só tirando uma dúvida contigo, dentro da pasta templates, vc tem? `printer/index.html`? lembrando que printer é uma pasta e o index.html tem que está dentro de printer.

Comment: Eu tive que mudar toda a estrutura em que o projeto se encontrava, eu tirei esse `template_folder = templete ` , e coloquei o printer/index.html ai deu certo

Comment: então se eu te ajudei, por favor avalie-me como a melhor resposta.